# How to put an argument vector with an argument containing spaces in a bash variable

Tags: bash, arguments

How can I store an argument vector with an argument containing spaces in a `bash` variable?

For example, I want `2.sh` to print `b c`

#### 1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

ARGV='a "b c"'
./2.sh $ARGV
```

#### 2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an array instead of a string:

```
args=("a" "b c")
./2.sh "${args[@]}"
```

When the array expansion is quoted, each element of the array is properly expanded.